# SQL: Eliminate duplicate entries by selecting ID but showing Name instead

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

How can I select by (ID) but still show distinct (Name) by the newest (Mod.Date) to eliminate the duplicates in the (Name) column. I'm assuming this is easy but i've never done this. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Can you post what you have done with the ID? We can help updating it.

Comment: Can you also show us what you expect the query to return (just to make sure we understand your question) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Subquery which selects the latest date for each ID:

```
SELECT t.ID, max(t.`mod.date`) last_date
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.ID
```

This subquery has to be linked to the original table using the ID and the date.

```
SELECT t.ID,t.Name,t.`mod.date`
FROM YourTable t
    JOIN (SELECT t.ID, max(t.`mod.date`) last_date
            FROM YourTable t
            GROUP BY t.ID) tmp ON tmp.ID=t.ID AND tmp.`mod.date`=t.`mod.date`
```

This gives you ID and (latest) Name for all IDs.

**Update**: Another possibility which should work in Access also is to use the `ALL` comparison:

```
SELECT t.ID,t.Name,t.`mod.date`
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.`mod.date` >= ALL (SELECT max(t1.`mod.date`) 
                FROM YourTable t1 
                WHERE t1.ID=t.ID GROUP BY t1.ID)
```

Comment: I'm actually doing this in Access 2010 and everything works fine until i enter in the temp table. Access doesnt recognize temp tables which stinks. Is there another way around this? Thanks for you help!

Comment: Why did you tag your question with Mysql then? I have updated my answer with an option which should work in Access too.

Comment: I apologize about tagging it with Mysql. Your answer is superb and works perfect. thank you